# $\{x=(x_1,0,x_3,0,...)\in \ell_2\}+{\overline{{\rm span}}\{u_n=\cos(\pi/{2n})e_{2n-1}+\sin(\pi/2n)e_{2n} | n \in \mathbb N\}}$ is dense in $\ell_2$

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $X=\{x=(x_1,x_2,...) \in \ell_2 | x_{2n} = 0 \ \forall n \in \mathbb N \}$, $Y=\overline{{\rm span}}\{y_n=\cos(\pi/{2n})e_{2n-1}+\sin(\pi/2n)e_{2n} | n \in \mathbb N\}$. How can I show that $X+Y$ is dense in $l_2$ i.e. $\overline{X+Y}=\ell_2$?

My idea was to take an arbitrary $z=(z_1,z_2,...) \in l_2$ and then construct $y=\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n(\cos(\pi/{2n})e_{2n-1}+\sin(\pi/2n)e_{2n}) \in Y$, where $a_n \in \mathbb K= \mathbb R$  or $\mathbb C \ \forall n $, and $x=(x_1,0,x_3,0,...) \in X$ with $x+y=z$ like that:

If $z_{2n} = 0: a_n=0$ and $x_{2n-1}=z_{2n-1}$

If $z_{2n} \neq 0: a_n = \frac{z_{2n}}{\sin(\pi/2n)}$, if $z_{2n-1} \neq 0: x_{2n-1}=y_{2n-1} - a_k\cos(\pi/{2n})$ if $z_{2n-1} = 0:$ define a sequence $(x_m)_m, x_m \in X \ \forall m$ with $x_{2n-1}=\frac{1}{m} - a_k\cos(\pi/{2n})$.

$\Rightarrow z=x+y$

However, I need to show that $y\in Y$ (wich is obvious) and $x \in X$. Therefore I need to show that $x \in \ell_2$ which I couldn't do. So if you could tell me how to show that or if (and if yes why) my idea is wrong, it would be very helpful to me.

Answer (score 0):

Thee is much simpler way of proving this. $X+Y$ is a subspace of $\ell^{2}$ and it is dense iff its orthogonal complement is $\{0\}$. So let $(y_n)$ be orthogonal to $X+Y$. Then $(y_n)$ is orthogonal to both $X$ and $Y$. Orthogonality to $X$ easily gives $y_n=0$ for all $n$ odd.  Now orthogonality to $Y$ gives $y_{2n} \sin (\frac {\pi} {2n})=0$ for all $n \geq 1$. But $\sin (\frac {\pi} {2n}) >0$ so this gives $y_n=0$ for all $n$ even.